# Don't understand why am I getting Error 1215: Foreign key can not be added

Tags: mysql-5.6

I am having a problem creating a database table. I have Done Something like:

`CREATE TABLE STREAM(
    STREAM_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    STREAM_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    TOTAL_SEM INT NOT NULL
)Engine=InnoDB;`

and then:

`CREATE TABLE SEMESTER(
    STREAM_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    SEMESTER INT NOT NULL,
    SUB_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    SUB_CODE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(STREAM_ID,SUB_CODE),
    CONSTRAINT STUDENT_STREAM_FK5 FOREIGN KEY (STREAM_ID) REFERENCES STREAM(STREAM_ID)
)Engine=InnoDB;`

It creates the Database Tables very well. But When I create another Table referencing the `SUB_CODE` in `SEMESTER` table it gives me Error: 1215:

`CREATE TABLE SUBJECT(
    Q_NO INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    SUB_CODE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    SEMESTER VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    SET_NO INT NOT NULL,
    Q_TYPE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    QUESTION VARCHAR(200) NOT  NULL,
    CHOICE_1 VARCHAR(30),
    CHOICE_2 VARCHAR(30),
    CHOICE_3 VARCHAR(30),
    CHOICE_4 VARCHAR(30),
    CORRECT VARCHAR(30),
    ANSWER VARCHAR(30),
    MARKS FLOAT,
    PRIMARY KEY(Q_NO,SUB_CODE),
    CONSTRAINT STUDENT_SEMESTER_FK6 FOREIGN KEY (SUB_CODE) REFERENCES SEMESTER(SUB_CODE)
)Engine=InnoDB;`

In that case while creating `SUBJECT` table it gives Error:1215. I don't understand, I have created the Table `SEMESTER` the same way I am tryng to create `SUBJECT`, then why it is not working?
I am using MySQL Server 5.6.

Please Help!
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it anyway. Just made it like:

`CREATE TABLE SUBJECT(
    Q_NO INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    SUB_CODE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL REFERENCES SEMESTER(SUB_CODE),
    SEMESTER VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    SET_NO INT NOT NULL,
    Q_TYPE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    QUESTION VARCHAR(200) NOT  NULL,
    CHOICE_1 VARCHAR(30),
    CHOICE_2 VARCHAR(30),
    CHOICE_3 VARCHAR(30),
    CHOICE_4 VARCHAR(30),
    CORRECT VARCHAR(30),
    ANSWER VARCHAR(30),
    MARKS FLOAT 
)Engine=InnoDB;`

I ignored making the `SUB_CODE` the primary key. And its done. Needed it to be the foreign key of the `SEMESTER` table anyway!